# Initialization and pushing data in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

First, I declare an array :

```
let arr = [];
```

Hence, I fill this array in the following way :

```
(async function loop() {
        for(let i=timeStart; i<=timeEnd; i+=3600000)
        {
          await ExternDataProvider.getCountData(i, (i+3600000), localSearchFilters)
            .then(function(dataResult){
              arr.push(dataResult);
            })
            .catch(function(err){
            });
        }
      })();
```

But, when I make a console.log of the variable "arr", I have the following result :

[image: output]

So why I dont have something like `[2251,215]` instead ?

Comment: So your 0 index is 2251 and your 1 index is 215, what is the problem?

Comment: It is the behaviour of [tag:console]

Comment: @Icepickle No, when I type arr[0] I have undefined.

Comment: where are you typing that

Comment: @James In a console.log just after this code.

Comment: It is solved, just a bad management of asynchronous programming, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `console.log()` your array after calling the function, you will have an empty array in the console, but after the data is resolved the console will refresh the content of the array. But if you `console.log(arr[0])` it will show you `undefined` immediatly.

In my opinion you should return your array (or resolve it) and capture the resolved value in another `then` and execute your `console.log` inside this `then`

Try this:

```
let arr = [];
setTimeout(function() {
    arr.push(1)
}, 5000);

console.log(arr[0]); // prints undefined
console.log(arr); // prints an empty array if you expand the array before 5 seconds, and it will print [1] if you re-expand it after 5 seconds
```

Comment: Exactly, It was just a bad management of asynchronous programming, and I have correct it. Sorry for my stupid topic. :-(

Comment: Glad that it helps, but I will be supeeeeeeeeeeeeeer happy if you validate my answer :p

Answer (score 0):

You have `[2251,215]`

But console shows it in a different way.

> The 0 means value in 0<sup>th</sup> position.
>
> The 1 means value in 1<sup>th</sup> position

Comment: No, when I do "arr[0]", I juste have undefined.

Comment: And when I do arr.length, I juste have 0.

Comment: the console shows length 2. Can you post the full code as a snippet?

Comment: When I type arr.length, I have 0.

Comment: please make a snippet

Comment: It is solved, just a bad management of asynchronous programming, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use `console.log(JSON.stringify(array))` to make that happen